# Array Curve modifer: deform issues (even after instance face; apply scale)

Tags: modifiers, curve-modifier

I have been stuck on the **array+curve modifier deforms** for several days.
I have refer to various blender tutorial videos & forums, but can't really find a clear solution.

**What I have done:**

1. I have applied rotation & scale of the object & path.
2. Tried to do instance+face methods.
3. Setting origin to start of the path, and align plane to the path origin.

**Issues:**

- When try above method with simple path and plane, the plane is scaled despite apply scale & set origin point on both path & plane where the array starts.
- When trying instance+face with different object, the object is rotated to wrong way.

**Example:**

- Below image shows the example issues:
- Array modifier is set as constant (with X-axis).
- Curve modifier is set as deform axis as X

**A.** instance+face method with custom object.

**B.** instance+face method with simple plane = plane deforms, not starting from the path origin; starts from the opposite side.

**C.** just array+curve modifier with simple cube.

---

**Edit: I have attached the example file, via blender exchange.**
[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the radius of the curve's control points? If no fix. maybe share your examples on https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks for the link, I didn't know how to upload the example file to the question. I have edited above question with the example file.